# Type of reference binding from std::tuple

Tags: c++, c++17, structured-bindings

What is the type of `a` here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float x{};
    std::tuple<int> tpl( x );
    auto& [ a ] = tpl;
    static_assert( std::is_same_v< decltype( a ), int> );
    //static_assert( std::is_same_v< decltype( a ), int&> );
}
```

According to Standard 11.5/3:

> [...]  Given the type Ti designated by `std::tuple_element<i, E>::type`,
>   variables are introduced with unique names ri of type **“reference to
>   Ti”** initialized with the initializer (11.6.3), **where the reference is
>   an lvalue reference if the initializer is an lvalue** and an rvalue
>   reference otherwise. Each vi is the name of an lvalue of type Ti that
>   refers to the object bound to ri; the referenced type is Ti.

Here, `i` is 0 for the first element (int) and `E` is `std::tuple<int>`, so `Ti` has type `std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<int>>::type`, i.e. `int`. Further `ri` (`a` in our case) has type "reference to Ti", i.e. lvalue reference `int&`, but not just `int`.
What is wrong in that quote and why `int` type is deduced by both the compilers clang and gcc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's true that the type of variable `r0` is `int&`.  But `v0`, here called `a`, is a different thing, the name of a structured binding, and is not technically a variable at all, just a different sort of name.

So we need to look at the description of `decltype`, in [[dcl.type.decltype]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.type.decltype):

> For an expression `e`, the type denoted by `decltype(e)` is defined as follows:
>
> - if `e` is an unparenthesized *id-expression* naming a structured binding, `decltype(e)` is the referenced type as given in the specification of the structured binding declaration;

So here the "referenced type" is just `int`.

Of course, `decltype((a))` is `int&` as we'd expect. `decltype` on a name without doubled parentheses is used to find out how a name is "declared", not how the name behaves, so it's not obvious that `decltype(a)` "should" be one thing or another, since `a` doesn't have a normal declaration.  Though it is potentially a bit useful that given `std::tuple<int, int&> t{0, n}; auto& [a, b] = t;`, we have `decltype(a)` is `int` but `decltype(b)` is `int&`.

Answer (score 1):

Note

> the referenced type is Ti.

For structured bindings, `decltype` yields the referenced type ([[dcl.type.decltype]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.decltype)):

> if `e` is an unparenthesized id-expression naming a structured binding, `decltype(e)` is the referenced type as given in the specification of the structured binding declaration;